# How to get value from "object_list" returned by listview

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I want to check the particular value from "object_list" returned by ListView in a template.

So I wrote code this way.

```
{% object_list.<primary key>.<column> %}
```

Example

```
{% if object_list.ABCD1234.item_name == "myitem" %}
...
do something
...
{% endif %}
```

In this example, ID(primarykey) is "ABCD1234" Column name is "item_name" and value in "item_name" is "myitem".

Maybe I wrote something wrong, it does not work at all.
Please teach me how to fix the code to get value from object_list to make the above conditional branching works well.

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: You can't lookup an object in a queryset this way in your template. Can you give a real world example of why you are trying to do this?

Comment: If you are after a single object you should use a `DetailView`. `ListView` is for iterating over a collection of objects.